# Group split data in timeline data in to one in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data which is shown below.

| stationName | status | startTime | endTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | normal | 09:00 | 09:10 |
| A | normal | 09:10 | 09:20 |
| B | normal | 09:30 | 09:40 |
| A | normal | 09:30 | 09:40 |
| B | normal | 09:40 | 09:45 |
| A | warning | 09:40 | 09:45 |
| B | warning | 09:45 | 09:55 |
| A | alert | 09:45 | 09:55 |
| B | normal | 09:55 | 10:05 |
| A | alert | 09:55 | 10:05 |
| B | normal | 10:05 | 10:15 |
| A | normal | 10:05 | 10:15 |
| B | normal | 10:15 | 10:25 |
| A | normal | 10:15 | 10:25 |
| B | normal | 10:25 | 10:35 |
| A | normal | 10:25 | 10:35 |

and I want to query data into this structure

| stationName | status | startTime | endTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | normal | 09:00 | 09:40 |
| A | warning | 09:40 | 09:45 |
| A | alert | 09:45 | 10:05 |
| A | normal | 10:05 | 10:35 |
| B | normal | 09:30 | 09:45 |
| B | warning | 09:45 | 09:55 |
| B | normal | 09:55 | 10:35 |

My data timeline data is split into many parts, but I want to group it into one.

Comment: next time, please use https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14  create your table, populate your table.

Comment: @mark Sorry, I will do it next time for sure and thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d89cf723a8063e6e3e29032d27850eb8)
idea: construct a range, test (startTime,endTime) belong to one specific timestamptz range or not,
then group by stationname, status, range(startTime, endTime) belong to.

I would use **timestamptz** type for startTime, endTime, tstzrange.
If you construct timerange, then range `(23:00,0:00)` is invalid.
table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE test102 (
    stationName text,
    status text,
    startTime timestamptz,
    endTime timestamptz
);
```

then query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        test102.*,
        tstzrange(startTime, endTime) tstzrange_se,
        tstzrange(i - interval '1 hour', i)
    FROM
        test102,
        generate_series('2022-05-02'::timestamp, '2022-05-02'::timestamp + interval '24 hour', interval '1 hour') i
)
SELECT
    stationname,
    status,
    min(startTime),
    max(endTime)
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    tstzrange_se <@ tstzrange
GROUP BY
    1,
    2,
    tstzrange;
```